# Change time zone on all sharepoint online sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

Im trying to change the time zones on all sharepoint sites in the tenant, but i am getting **"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." error.**

My user is Global Admin and Sharepoint Admin with MFA enabled.

```
$adminurl ="https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$timezone ="(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlijn, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Wenen"

#Connect To SharePoint Online
$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential

#Connect To SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminurl

#Get all Site Collections
$SitesCollection = Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL

#Change timezone for alle SPO Sites
ForEach($Site in $SitesCollection)
{
Write-host -f Yellow "Setting Timezone for Site Collection:"$Site.URL

Set-SPOnlineTimeZone -SiteURL $Site.URL -TimezoneName $timezone -cred $AdminCredentials

}
```

Comment: How do you parse the admin credentials? This part is missing in the code, since you only ask for $admincredentials. After a quick google, it seems like SharePoint only accepts a special cred-object rather than the by default created cred-object from Get-Credentials.

Comment: Where is `Set-SPOnlineTimeZone` defined? From what I can see, this isn't part of the `SharePointOnlinePowerShell` module.

Comment: @Bowshock Sorry, seems like i did not have the full script in the orgiginal post:
#Connect To SharePoint Online
$AdminCredentials = Get-Credential

Comment: Please try the following two lines: $Cred= Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

- theres a specific sharepoint credentials object, try if that works.